# Javascript function doesn't return query result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out why one of my queries won't return the value from a query...my code looks like this:

```
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

var query = client.query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM sat_scores")

// Don't use demo key in production. Get a key from https://api.nasa.gov/index.html#apply-for-an-api-key

function getNEO(callback) {
    var data = '';
    query.on('rows', function(rows) {
        console.log("Row count is: %s", rows[0].count)
        data += rows[0].count;
    });
    query.on('end', function() {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

with that, getNEO returns a blank...but if I set `var data = '4'`, then getNEO returns 4....the query should return 128 but it just returns a blank...

Comment: Seems like the `data` event might be triggered? Does the `console.log` show up in your console?

Comment: @FelixKling, seems like the `query.on('data',...` is not being triggered...changed the `'data'` to `'rows'` too but that didn't work either...

Comment: So that's the reason then why the empty value is passed. Now you have to figure out how to actually get the data.

Comment: @FelixKling any idea why? I tried moving the `var query =` inside the `getNEO` function but still no luck...

Comment: Have you checked whether your query is failing with an error?

Comment: You need to show us where `getNEO` is being called, and what callback is being passed to it, and where you are not seeing a value that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `getNEO()` doesn't *return* anything - I'm operating on the assumption that you call `getNEO()` exactly once for your `query`, and pass in a callback to handle the data, and that callback is what's not getting the appropriate data?

My typical recommendation for troubleshooting things like this is to simplify your code, and try and get really close to any example code given ([for instance](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)):

```
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
// define your callback here, in theory
client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var query = client.query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM sat_scores"),
        function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log(result.rows.length);
        }
    );
});
```

... I'm doing a couple things here you'll want to note:

1. It looks like the `client.connect()` method is asynchronous - you can't just connect and then go run your query, you have to wait until the connection is completed, hence the callback.  Looking through the code, it looks like it may emit a `connect` event when it's ready to send queries, so you don't have to use a callback on the `connect()` method directly.
2. I don't see a `data` event [in the documentation for the query object](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Query) nor do I see one in the code.  You could use the `row` event, or you could use a callback directly on the query as in the example on the main page - that's what I've done here in the interest of simplicity.
3. I don't see the `count` property you're using, and `row[0]` is only going to be the first result - I think you want the `length` property on the whole `rows` array if you're looking for the number of rows returned.

I don't know if you have a good reason to use the `getNEO()` function as opposed to putting the code directly in procedurally, but I think you can get a closer approximation of what you're after like this:

```
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
// define your callback here, in theory
client.connect();

function getNEO(callback) {
    client.on('connect', function () {
        var query = client.query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM sat_scores"));

        query.on('end', function(result) {
            callback(result.rowCount);
        });
    });
}
```

... so, you can call your `getNEO()` function whenever you like, it'll appropriately wait for the connection to be completed, and then you can skip tracking each row as it comes; the `end` event receives the `result` object which will give you all the rows and the row count to do with what you wish.

Comment: docs says it's better use cliente pooling:  var pool = new pg.Pool(config);
// to run a query we can acquire a client from the pool, 
// run a query on the client, and then return the client to the pool 
pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {

Comment: @stackdave excellent advice - once you get basic working code, the next step is understand the appropriate best practices to do first level optimizations, such as using client pooling.

Answer (score -1):

so here is how I was able to resolve the issue....I moved the `var query` inside of the function

```
function getNEO(state, callback) {
    var conString = "postgres://alexa:al@alexadb2.cgh3p2.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/alexa";

    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect();
    var data = '';
    var query = client.query("SELECT avg(Math) as math,  avg(Reading) as reading FROM sat_scores WHERE State = '" + state + "'");
    console.log("query is: %s", query);
    query.on('row', function(row) {
            console.log("Row cnt is: %s", row.math);
            console.log("row is: " + row)
            data += row;
        });
    console.log("made it");
    query.on('end', function() {
    callback(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: accord docs you must to do always:  var client = new pg.Client(); 
// connect to our database
client.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;  ...